# Can Entity Framework map two associations into a single navigation?

Tags: entity-framework

I have two simple tables as described here...

```
Table = Person
   PersonID  (int, PrimaryKey)
   FirstName (char)
   LastName  (char)

Table = Related
   RelatedID    (int, PrimaryKey)
   Person1      (int, ForeignKey for Person.PersonID)
   Person2      (int, ForeignKey for Person.PersonID)
   Relationship (int)
```

The generated entity for Person has two navigation collections. One for the Related.Person1 and another for Related.Person2. This is a pain because it means I have two collections to investigate to look up all the relationships that are relevant to that person.

I need to have instead just a single navigation collections that contains both of these sets. Is it possible to have this generated as part of the entity frameowrk? The only alternative is to generate a third collection myself that contains the aggregate set of entities and it feels like that should not be needed.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. If you added an entity to the proposed, merged collection, how would the EF know in which of your two collections to put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Craig states what you are asking for is not something core to EF but... a friendship type relationship is one of those nasty ones to model, so I see what you are trying to do.

There is a workaround to make this possible by mapping the Association Set to a view (DefiningQuery) in the SSDL.

The association/relationship backed by the view will then be read-only, so you will probably want to leave the other two relationships in place to allow you to add / remove from the correct collection or for when you want to search in one direction only.

Check out this post [which shows the techniques](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2008/02/26/associations-with-payloads-closing-the-loop.aspx) involved for more.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was thinking that you have two nodes A and B that are stored and there is a relationship between them. I only want to store that relationship once. But I want to know about the relationship from node A and from node B. So it is stored once but represented in two places, the two ends of the relationship.

Comment: Storing it once, but representing it in multiple places is what I was suggesting. In fact that is what that blog post does.